# mouse click using sendMessage issue

Tags: vb.net, sendmessage, mouseclick-event, mouse-coordinates

after working like 3 hours I finally managed to make a code to make a mouse click inside a window without moving the cursor, or having the window active using sendMessage. Here is some of my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
    Dim x As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim y As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    If (hw) Then
        SendMessage(hw, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MAKELONG(x, y))
        SendMessage(hw, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELONG(x, y))
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried it in notepad and it works great. However, I am trying to do it inside a game, but for some reason the x,y is not working, the click happens at my last mouse position inside the game. Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps the game doesn't trust all the window messages it receives and decides to query the system for the mouse position instead of trusting the coordinates some random message provides.

Comment: Change the `Cursor.Position` property before sending the click.

Comment: Where is your code for MAKELONG() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the mousemove event to the window first like e.g.:

```
Public Const WM_MOUSEMOVE = &H200
SendMessage(MainWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, MakeDWord(P.X, P.Y))
```

If this doesn't work, try adding Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) after the mouse move event is send to the window.